# log_reuse_Wait_desc always return LOG_BACKUP even right after log backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log, log

We are using SQL Server 2012 standard Edition (SP4)- 11.0.700.0(x64) (Build 14393)(HYpervisor).

Data File Size = 171 GB
Log File Size = 106 GB

When I queried `sys.databases` to see the `log_reuse_Wait_desc` it is always `LOG_BACKUP`- even right after log backup!
When I run `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)` I see "Log space Used %" is less than 1%.
`DBCC loginfo` returns 773 which is high.

FYI- This database is not involved in Log Shipping/replication/mirroring.  The recovery model for this DB is Full and log backups are taken every 30 minutes. I know log backups are happening as I checked from `msdb.dbo.backupset`.

This database had % autogrowth setting on log file until last week. I changed it as part of config change.

How do I find why the `log_reuse_desc` is returning `LOG_BACKUP` always?

I would like to explore some options to reduce the log file size on the disk. (I know it is a bad bad thing to trucate and shrink the log file, but at this point I would like to know my options available). Can someone please suggest a graceful way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When I queried sys.databases to see the log_reuse_Wait_desc it is always LOG_BACKUP- even right after log backup! how do I find why the log_reuse_desc is returning LOG_BACKUP always.**

This is nicely explained by Paul Randal:

> Imagine a database where there’s very little insert/update/delete/DDL
>   activity, so in between your regular log backups there are only a few
>   log records generated, and they’re all in the same VLF. The next log
>   backup runs, backing up those few log records, but it can’t clear the
>   current VLF, so can’t clear log_reuse_wait_desc. As soon as there are
>   enough changes in the database that the current VLF fills up and the
>   next VLF is activated, the next log backup should be able to clear the
>   previous VLF and then the log_reuse_wait_desc will revert to NOTHING.
>   Until the next log backup occurs and isn’t able to clear the current
>   VLF, in which case it will go back to LOG_BACKUP again.
>
> So LOG_BACKUP really means “either you need to take a log backup, or
>   the log records that were backed up were all in the current VLF and so
>   it could not be cleared.”

Full article: [Why is log_reuse_wait_desc saying LOG_BACKUP after doing a log backup?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-is-log_reuse_wait_desc-saying-log_backup-after-doing-a-log-backup/)

**I would like to explore some options to reduce the log file size on the disk.**

Before you shrink the log files it is also important for you to understand how you end up with too many or too less number of VLF's. I suggest you read the following posts. These will give you a better idea about VLF and transaction log management.

1. [A Busy/Accidental DBA’s Guide to Managing VLFs](http://adventuresinsql.com/2009/12/a-busyaccidental-dbas-guide-to-managing-vlfs/) by David Levy
2. [How do you clear the SQL Server transaction log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log) by Aaron Bertrand
3. Aaron added 4 more links at the bottom of his answer, all those are very useful and related to your question.
4. [Transaction Log VLFs – too many or too few?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/transaction-log-vlfs-too-many-or-too-few/) by Kimberly Tripp

Comment: appreciate pointing to the relevant links.Followed Aaron Bertrand's post and was able to reduce the log file size to a proper size. So far so good...